# How to display an image located in another drive?

Tags: php, html, iis

I have two drives:

- C: (where the IIS is located)
- D: (where all images are located)

What I want to do is to use the images in the other drive and be able to display them in my site in the other drive.

For example, I have an image called "flower.jpg" located in D: (D:/flower.jpg) and I want to use it in my site. I tried something like this (and as I thought, it doesn't work -- and again, the IIS is in C:):

```
<img src="D:/flower.jpg"></img>
```

I also tried with file:/ and file:/// and none worked too.

```
<img src="file:/D:/flower.jpg"></img>
```

How could I do it?

Comment: Put your images in the C:\ drive.

Comment: Yeah, that's not an option. At least not at the moment. Anything else? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't use drive letters in your webserver. Everything is served from the root of the webserver (which is C:\inetpub I believe). You webserver only has access to that folder and should only have access to that folder.

If it's a limited space problem you're having, the easiest solution is moving your inetpub folder to you D: drive [like so](https://domainwebcenter.com/move-inetpub-directory/) and place the images under that folder.

Comment: Yeah, that's not an option. At least not at the moment. Anything else? Thanks!